# Why is this css not working in firefox and ie11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to change the button color in woocommerce with this:

```
#top .button, #top .submitbutton {
text-shadow: none!important; 
color: white!important;
font-weight: bold; !important; 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6FB56F),        to(#0D850D))!important;
```

It works fine in chrome but does not work in ie11 and firefox. All answers are greatly appreciated

Comment: `-webkit-` is just for Webkit, including Safari/Chrome/Opera15+
You should add the other vendor prefixes for the `gradient` property as well.

Answer (score 2):

If it is only the background that isn't working you need to define the web browser specific gradients:

i.e.
As an example:

```
#grad
{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Would allow for the gradients to work on those browsers.

See [here for details](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

Comment: Your "standard syntax" is wrong, and vendor prefixes are unnecessary.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol syntax is absolutely correct http://jsfiddle.net/7xTVQ/ unless you want to define the direction your way

Comment: Huh, fair enough. Still, it's better to define the direction :p

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Agreed. It's always better clearly define what you want than leave it to the browser to assume the defaults. It helps with unexpected behaviour when the browser gets upgraded/changes since you have all your arguments defined.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do a gradient is:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5FB56F, #0D850D);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(); /* Chrome and Safari */
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(); /* Old Firefox (3.6 to 15) */
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(); /* Pre-releases of IE 10 */
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(); /* Old Opera (11.1 to 12.0) */ 
  background-image:         linear-gradient(); /* Standard syntax; Works best if last */
```

Comment: And `background-image: linear-gradient()` too, of course.

Comment: It should be noted that the standard syntax doesn't have to be last, assuming you're defining the same gradient.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol What if a browser supports both a buggy vendor prefix and the standard `linear-gradient`? Anyway, if you are sure, please fix the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Cross-browser_gradients)

Comment: @Oriol Depends what you mean by buggy. If you define the *same* gradient, order doesn't matter. Or you could just not use prefixes, since [all browsers support unprefixed gradients now](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradients).

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit` works only for Safari/Chrome/Opera.
For appropriate to Firefox, use `-moz` and for IE9 use `-ms`.